# accessing session variables in javascript inside jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, session-variables

I need to provide data for google APIs table... so I'll send it from servlet to JSP

but how can I access this data in "googles" javascript?

I'll provide sample of another JS - very simple one - just to let me learn how to make what topic says

```
    <script>
        function showTable()
        {
            <%
                Object obj = session.getAttribute("list");
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                int size = 0; 

                if (obj != null) {
                    list = (ArrayList<String>) obj;
                    size = (Integer) session.getAttribute("size");
                }

                for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
                    String value = list.get(i);

            %>
                    alert('<%= i %> = <%= value %> ');
            <%
                }

            %>                
        }
    </script>
```

It has to print elements of given list... but now it's just a big scriplet with alert inside of it... for to refactor it? I don't like having to much java in JSPs, because servlet is where it should be placed

EDIT: just to sum up - I would prefer "normal" JS for loop here... Generally I'd prefer to minimize java code, and maximize JS

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Convert it to [JSON](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_%28_JavaScript_Object_Notation_%29) in `doGet()` of a preprocessing servlet. You can use among others [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for this. Assuming that you've a `List<Person>`:

```
List<Person> persons = createItSomehow();
String personsJson = new Gson().toJson(persons);
request.setAttribute("personsJson", personsJson);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/persons.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

*(note that I made it a request attribute instead of session attribute, you're free to change it, but I believe it doesn't necessarily need to be a session attribute as it does not represent sessionwide data)*

Assign it to a JS variable in JSP as follows:

```
<script>
    var persons = ${personsJson};
    // ...
</script>
```

This way it's available as a fullworthy JS object. You could feed it straight to the Google API.

Now invoke the URL of the servlet instead of the JSP. For example, when it's mapped on an URL pattern of `/persons`, invoke it by http://localhost:8080/contextname/persons.

Comment: wow, thanks Balus. It looks great. And... it even works :) I've used some other JSON implementation, but code looked similar. Readability is awesome :)

Comment: But btw. I found out, that I passed List object to request instead of jsonarray, and it worked fine. So what's the benefit of using json? It's only for escaping special characters?

Comment: It works indeed when you use `List<String>`. The [`List#toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString%28%29) has the coincidence that it matches the JS array syntax. But you shouldn't rely on it. Definitely not when you have a `List<SomeComplexObject>` of which each item is represented by `SomeComplexObject#toString()`. And yes, JSON format is also much more robust when it comes to handling special characters.

Comment: It was worthy to me because I couldn't access SessionScope variables due to it was java objects. With Gson, now I'm able to treat it.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is executed at client side, and scriptlets, EL, and JSP tags at server side. From the point of view of the server-side code, JavaScript is just generated text, just like HTML markup.

So, if you want to have a JavaScript loop which loops over a JavaScript array in the generated HTML page, you need to generate the JavaScript code which initializes the array, and the JavaScript loop.

Here's the JSP code

```
var theArray = [<c:forEach items="${sessionScope.list}" var="item" varStatus="loopStatus">'${item}' <c:if ${!loopStatus.last}>, </c:if></c:forEach>];
for (var i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
    alert(theArray[i]);
}
```

This JSP code will generate the following JavaScript code, assuming the list in the session attribute contains "banana", "apple" and "orange":

```
var theArray = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', ];
for (var i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
    alert(theArray[i]);
}
```

Make sure, though, to properly escape the values of the list in order to generate valid JavaScript code. For example, if one of the values was `"I'm cool"`, the generated JavaScript would be

```
var theArray = ['I'm cool', 'apple', 'orange', ];
```

which is not valid anymore. Use commons-lang [StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.0.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeEcmaScript%28java.lang.String%29) to escape the values.

Comment: note that the ['banana',] array will have 2 values the last being undefined

Comment: @Liviu: thanks for this useful note. I tested on Firefox, and it only contains the 3 fruits. On IE, though, it contains the 3 fruits + undefined. Anyway, I just wanted to show the idea of generating a JavaScript array. I'll fix it to avoid the last comma.

Comment: `error: missing = in XML attribute   var theArray = [<c:forEach items="[1, 2222, 3333]" var="item" varStatus="loopStatus">'' <c:if true>, </c:if></c:forEach>]; ` what's wrong with it and can I fix this? List is created by: ` List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); list.add("1"); list.add("2222"); list.add("3333"); session.setAttribute("list", list);`

Answer (score 0):

since the ArrayList is having objects of Strings you can simply use split() method on the value of the array list. Something like as below;

```
function showTable() {  
  <%
       Object obj = session.getAttribute("list");
       List list = null;
       if (obj != null) {
           list = (ArrayList<String>) obj;
       } else list = new ArrayList<String>();  %>
var jsList = <%=list.toString()%>

//remove [] from content
jsList = jsList.replace("[","");
jsList = jsList.replace("]","");
```

`//split the contents`
`var splitContent = jsList.split(","); //an array of element`

```
for(var i=0;i<splitContent.length;++i) {
  alert(splitContent[i]);
}
```

`}`

I hope this will help you solve this.