# put bean values in external JS files

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts, javabeans

Is there a simply way to read bean values in a .js file?

I have an external JS file, arrays.js, which contains some arrays, used to populate a series of  within a JSP page.

Now I need to fill the content of those arrays reading  values.

I have to use the external js file, because it also contains lots of other methods to make the application work.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is to let JSP print it as a global JS variable so that it's visible to the scripts which execute after DOM ready. E.g.

```
<script>var bean = ${beanAsJson};</script>
```

where `${beanAsJson}` prints the bean in JSON format. You could use among others [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for this.

Another way is to let the JS code send an ajax request to a servlet which writes exactly that bean in JSON format to the response. E.g. with little help of [jQuery](http://jquery.org):

```
$.getJSON('jsonServlet', function(bean) {
    // ...
});
```

#### See also:

- [accessing session variables in javascript inside jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241442/accessing-session-variables-in-javascript-inside-jsp/7242678#7242678)
- [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax)
- [Populating cascading dropdown lists in JSP/Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263996/populating-child-dropdownlists-in-jsp-servlet)

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know how to write that kind servlet, so in the main JSP, which does the include of the .js file, I will do something like:
var arr={msg1:<bean1>, msg2:<bean2>}
so that I can access arr from arrays.js

Answer (score 0):

In `arrays.js` file create a function `function populateArray(arg1, arg2)`. Now you have a global function accessible from anywhere on your page, pass the values that you want to populate the arrays with as arguments to `populateArray` function and inside the function write the logic to populate your arrays.

Comment: The explanation would be enhanced with a code snippet